# Return True every other weekend, return False any other day

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a script that will run every other weekend, I've tried using datetime for that (a solution I found on the internet, likewise), but it always prints the entire week.

```
from datetime import date, timedelta
reference_monday = date(2016, 1, 8)        # any monday of a "week one"

schedule = [[True, True, True, True, True, True, True],
            [True, True, True, True, True, False, False]]

def check_date(d):
    return schedule[abs(d - reference_monday).days / 7 % 2][d.weekday()]

start = date(2012, 6, 4)

for w in range(6):
    thisweek = start + timedelta(weeks=w)
    print 'week of', thisweek, ':',
    print ','.join(str(check_date(thisweek + timedelta(days=d))) for d in range(7))
```

it returns

```
week of 2012-06-04 : True,True,True,True,True,True,True
week of 2012-06-11 : True,True,True,True,True,False,False
week of 2012-06-18 : True,True,True,True,True,True,True
week of 2012-06-25 : True,True,True,True,True,False,False
week of 2012-07-02 : True,True,True,True,True,True,True
week of 2012-07-09 : True,True,True,True,True,False,False
```

I would like it to return either true or false, depending on that current day.

Comment: Might be worth using `cron`, `Task Scheduler`, or a similar tool if available. Plenty of things that already schedule for you.

Comment: "but it always prints the entire week." well yeah, That's what I'd expect `..thisweek + timedelta(days=d))) for d in range(7)` to do.  the function itself does return a boolean every time, you are just calling it 7 times for each week.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comments, there are better alternatives to scheduling tasks.

Is this what you want?

```
def check_date(d):
    return not schedule[abs(d - reference_monday).days / 7 % 2][d.weekday()]
```

Output

```
week of 2012-06-04 : False,False,False,False,False,False,False
week of 2012-06-11 : False,False,False,False,False,True,True
week of 2012-06-18 : False,False,False,False,False,False,False
week of 2012-06-25 : False,False,False,False,False,True,True
week of 2012-07-02 : False,False,False,False,False,False,False
week of 2012-07-09 : False,False,False,False,False,True,True
```

> I would like it to return either true or false, depending on that current day

```
start = date(2012, 6, 4)
for w in range(6):
    thisweek = start + timedelta(weeks=w)
    print 'week of', thisweek, ':',

    # Only Saturday and Sunday
    run_sat = check_date(thisweek + timedelta(days=5))
    run_sun = check_date(thisweek + timedelta(days=6))

    print "{:5} | {:5}".format(str(run_sat), str(run_sun))
```

Outputs

```
week of 2012-06-04 : False | False
week of 2012-06-11 : True  | True 
week of 2012-06-18 : False | False
week of 2012-06-25 : True  | True 
week of 2012-07-02 : False | False
week of 2012-07-09 : True  | True
```